# Custom LinearLayout calling method

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement a custom LinearLayout that shows a DialogFragment. I did all, and it works great, the Dialog is showing and working perfectly, but I can't seem to get the data from the DialogFragment.

So I've created an interface:

```
public interface DialogCommunicator {void onDismiss(String format, String data);}
```

On the LinearLayout I've implemented the DialogCommunicator interface and done this:

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout implements DialogCommunicator, View.OnClickListener {

Button showDialog;
TextView displayUserInput;

CreateDialog dialog;

public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    showDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDialog);
    displayUserInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayUserInput);

    showDialog.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(String format, String data) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    someMethod(format, data);
}

private void someMethod(String format, String data) {
    displayUserInput.setText(format + data);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();
    dialog = new CreateDialog();
    dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Mydialog");
}}
```

On the DialogFragment I did this, but activity is allways null:

```
public class CreateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogCommunicator, View.OnClickListener {

View view;
String format, data;
Button create;
EditText userFormat, userData;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_barcode, container);
    userFormat = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userFormat);
    userData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userData);
    create = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.create);
    create.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onDismiss(String format, String data) {
    RTToolbarHorizontalLayout layout = (RTToolbarHorizontalLayout) getHost();
    if (layout != null) {
        layout.onDismiss(format, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    format = userFormat.getText().toString();
    data = userData.getText().toString();

    onDismiss(format, data);
}
}
```

I've tried getContext(), getDialog(), getHost() but they are all null.

Comment: Can you add all the code, will make it more clear

Comment: I've added the whole class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used an broadcast receiver so send data from the DialogFragment to the layout. Here is the CustomLayout:

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

Button showDialog;
TextView displayUserInput;

CreateDialog dialog;

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    String format = null;
    String data = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra("format") != null)
            format = intent.getStringExtra("format");
        if (intent.getStringExtra("barcode") != null)
            data = intent.getStringExtra("barcode");
        if (format != null && data != null) {
            someMethod(format, data);
            format = null;
            data = null;
        }
    }
};

public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter("com.exemple.myapplication.DATA_SEND"));
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    getContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    showDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDialog);
    displayUserInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayUserInput);

    showDialog.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void someMethod(String format, String data) {
    displayUserInput.setText(format + data);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getContext();
    dialog = new CreateDialog();
    dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
}}
```

Here is the implementation in the DialogFragment:

```
public class CreateDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {



View view;
String format, data;
Button create;
EditText userFormat, userData;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_barcode, container);
    userFormat = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userFormat);
    userData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userData);
    create = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.create);
    create.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    format = userFormat.getText().toString();
    data = userData.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent("com.exemple.myapplication.DATA_SEND");
    i.putExtra("format", format);
    i.putExtra("data", data);

    getContext().sendBroadcast(i);
}}
```